# Azure PowerBI Embedded - unable to delete workspace ID

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a account in azure Power BI embedded workspace and created workspace ID with in workspace collection.fist time created sample workspace ID , now  I want to remove sample workspace id ,how to delete workspace id  in C#?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available yet. It will be added at some point in the future

Comment: no option is there in azure Portal to delete workspace